# Webpack Unable to bundle two controllers in single file

Tags: angularjs, webpack, nodes

I am using webpack to bundle my files with angular 1.x
ON making bundle facing the issue that is

my first file is app.js where I write

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('kinatorApp', ['ui.router','ngCookies','oc.lazyLoad','ngResource','ngDraggable','restangular','oi.select','ui.bootstrap','toastr','LocalStorageModule','ngMessages','ngMaterial','ngScrollable']);
```

and my second file is parentController.js
    where my code is

```
    sampleApp.controller("parentCtrl", ['$scope','$rootScope','$compile','$http','$filter','$state','userServices','labelServices','sharedValues','groupServices','channelListService','parentControllerServices','toastr','positioningDataServices','$mdDialog', '$mdMedia', '$window','notification',
        function($scope,$rootScope,$compile,$http,$filter,$state,userServices,labelServices,sharedValues,groupServices,channelListService,parentControllerServices,toastr,positioningDataServices,$mdDialog, $mdMedia, $window,notification) {}]);
```

IN webpack I include these two files by

```
 require('./public/app.js');
 require('./public/ParentController.js');
```

my bundle is successfully made by on load it in index.html it says

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sampleApp is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:471)
    at Object.122 (bundle.js:1200)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:55)
    at Object.120 (bundle.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (vendor.js:26)
    at bundle.js:1
```

Unable to get sampleApp from app.js file in bundle

then I made sampleApp a global variable by

```
externals: {
        'sampleApp': ''
    }
```

But it also did,t work
I am using angular 1.x

Comment: I will recommend using  angular.module('kinatorApp').controller(); instaed of sampleApp.controller(). It seems sampleapp has become a private variable inside your bundle.

Comment: Even taking the sampleApp variable as global in webpack also solves my problem.